# Restart background worker

Tags: c#, .net, backgroundworker

Is there a way to directly "restart" a background worker?
Calling CancelAsync() followed by RunWorkerAsync() clearly won't do it as their names imply.

Background info:
I have a background worker which calculates a total in my .net 2.0 Windows Forms app.
Whenever the user modifies any value which is part of this total I'd like to restart the background worker in case it would be running so that directly the latest values are considered.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The backgriound work itself does not do any cancleing.

When you call `bgw.CancelAsync` it sets a flag on the background worker that you need to check yourself in the DoWork handler.

something like:

```
bool _restart = false;

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    bgw.CancelAsync();
    _restart = true;
}

private void bgw_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{

    for (int i = 0; i < 300; i++)
    {
        if (bgw.CancellationPending)
        {
            break;
        }
        //time consuming calculation
    }
}

private void bgw_WorkComplete(object sender, eventargs e)  //no ide to hand not sure on name/args
{
    if (_restart)
    {
        bgw.RunWorkerAsync();
        _restart = false;
    }

}
```

Comment: I'm very much aware of this. The question is about whether there is any other mechanism that allows to directly (force?) quit and restart the background worker.

Comment: That is not what your question implied.  And no there isn't, As Eric said, you will just have to use a Thread and abort that manually.

Answer (score 2):

There are a couple of options, it all depends on how you want to skin this cat:

If you want to continue to use `BackgroundWorker`, then you need to respect the model that has been established, that is, one of "progress sensitivity".  The stuff inside `DoWork` is clearly required to always be aware of whether or not the a pending cancellation is due (i.e., there needs to be a certain amount of polling taking place in your `DoWork` loop).

If your calculation code is monolithic and you don't want to mess with it, then don't use `BackgroundWorker`, but rather fire up your own thread--this way you can forcefully kill it if needs be.

Comment: OK that sounds interesting.
Can you recommend any specific documentation for using threads directly?

Comment: Check this MSDN link: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.thread.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You can hook the change event handler for the controls in which the values are changed and do the following in the handler:

```
if(!bgWrkr.IsBusy)
     //start worker
else if(!bgWrkr.CancellationPending)
  bgWrkr.CancelAsync();
```

Hope it helps you!

Comment: This doesn't solve the problem but just outlines it: If I call CancelAsync() in your example then the background worker won't be restarted to re-calculate with the latest values. Calling RunWorkerAsync() after CancelAsync() also won't fix the problem as the cancellation is handled asynchronosly...

Answer (score 0):

I want to leave my requests running, but no longer care about the results.  I override the value of the background worker (my busy spinner is using the isBusy flag).

```
    private void SearchWorkerCreate() {
        this.searchWorker = new BackgroundWorker();
        this.searchWorker.DoWork += this.SearchWorkerWork;
        this.searchWorker.RunWorkerCompleted += this.SearchWorkerFinish;
    }

    private void SearchWorkerStart(string criteria){
        if(this.searchWorker.IsBusy){
            this.SearchWorkerCreate();
        }
        this.searchWorker.RunWorkerAsync(criteria);
        this.OnPropertyChanged(() => this.IsBusy);
        this.OnPropertyChanged(() => this.IsIdle);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

May this method help someone... I've created a function to reset the backgroundworker in one method. I use it for task to do periodically.

By creating a `Task`, the backgroundworker is can be stopped with the `CancelAsync` and restarted inside the Task. Not making a Task wil start the backgroundworker again before it is cancelled, as the OP describes.

**The only requirement is that your code runs through some loop, which checks the CancellationPending every period of time (`CheckPerMilliseconds`).**

```
private void ResetBackgroundWorker()
{
    backgroundWorker.CancelAsync();

    Task taskStart = Task.Run(() => 
    {
        Thread.Sleep(CheckPerMilliseconds);
        backgroundWorker.RunWorkerAsync();
    });
}
```

Inside the backgroundworker I use a for-loop that checks the CancellationPending.

```
private void BackgroundWorker_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
    BackgroundWorker worker = sender as BackgroundWorker;

    while(true)
    {
        if (backgroundWorker.CancellationPending)
        {
            return;
        }

        //Do something you want to do periodically.

        for (int i = 0; i < minutesToDoTask * 60; i++)
        {
            if (backgroundWorker.CancellationPending)
            {
                return;
            }

            Thread.Sleep(CheckPerMilliseconds);
        }
    }
}
```